# jQuery loop slice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to truncate the characters of some sections that are automatically generated.
While I can see that it does the job on the console, it doesn't appear on the website (https://help.peeba.com/hc/zh-tw)

My code:

```js
if ($(location.href.indexOf("zh-tw") > -1) || (location.href.indexOf("zh-cn"))) {

  var str = $('.p-article-description').text();
  var res = str.slice(0, 48);
  $('.p-article-description').each(
    function(i, v) {
      $('.p-article-description').slice(0, 40);

  });
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: `.slice` on a string returns a new string. you have to assign it to something.

Comment: And whats up with the `var res = ...` you are never using this value in your example.

Comment: @Red I am testing multiple variants on how to achieve this. In the above code, the variables have no purpose. I've achieved this, however, now the text gets replicated to all the sections. So, working on that:
`code`
if ($(window.location.href.indexOf("zh-tw") > -1) || (window.location.href.indexOf("zh-cn"))) {


  $('.p-article-description').each(
    function(i, v) {
 var str = $('.p-article-description').text();
  var res = str.slice(0, 48);
      $('.p-article-description').text(res);

  });
}
`code`

Answer (score 0):

### Here is how I solved it.

if ($(window.location.href.indexOf("zh-tw") > -1) || (window.location.href.indexOf("zh-cn"))) {

```
$('.p-article-description').each(function() {
  if($(this).text().length > 100){
    $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0,100));
  }    
});
```